# How do I stop IFileDialog from resolving shortcuts to their targets?

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm trying to get the path to a shortcut using a file dialog. Here is an extract from my code to illustrate what I am doing:

```
IFileOpenDialog *pfod = NULL;
IShellItem *psiResult;
PWSTR pszFilePath = NULL;
....
pfod->Show(NULL);
pfod->GetResult(&psiResult);
psiResult->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &pszFilePath);
```

When I select a shortcut in the file dialog, for instance `<some path>\Internet.lnk`, the call to GetDisplayName returns the target of the shortcut `C:\Program Files(x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplorer.exe`. I would like to obtain the path to the shortcut, the .lnk file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the file dialog resolves shortcuts to their targets. The shell item returned to you has already been resolved and at that point it's too late to do anything. You need to include [`FOS_NODEREFERENCELINKS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn457282.aspx) in the file dialog's options to stop it performing shortcut resolution.

> **FOS_NODEREFERENCELINKS**
>
> Shortcuts should not be treated as their target items. This allows an application to open a .lnk file rather than what that file is a shortcut to.

Your code to set the options would look like this:

```
FILEOPENDIALOGOPTIONS fos;
pfod->GetOptions(&fos);
pfod->SetOptions(fos | FOS_NODEREFERENCELINKS);
```

Note that I have followed your example of ignoring return values, for the sake of a simple exposition.

Comment: If anybody have a problem(older Windowses) with writing to file after using OpenDialog here is solution: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/39cbc46a-2ad5-4300-8f08-4ca1469d6f76/writing-to-file-after-using-openfiledialog?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: @pors The real problem there is that in a GUI app you should not be using relative paths because the working directory is not in a reliable location.